# How can I uniquely Insert data into a table without using Unique/Primary key keyword in SQL? Is there any other way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I want to insert data into the columns where no data can be inserted more than once! No data of same type/Category can be same!
 I Know the easier / best way is to use defining the attribute as UNIQUE / PRIMARY KEY ... But there any others ways to do this!

Comment: you have to verify the data first before inserting

Comment: At least no good way.

Comment: You mean, by checking every time with every data of the column, right?

Comment: @SakibHasan maybe you should accept the answer

Comment: yup did it! I couldn't accept then as the system didn't me accept too early! :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the data before inserting it, by using a group by clause, or distinct or a join. It really depends on your requirement.

For example, if the data is exactly identical , using `DISTINCT` is enough:

```
INSERT INTO <YourTable>
SELECT DISTINCT ...
FROM ...
```

Or directly check if the data exists in the table:

```
INSET INTO <YourTable>
SELECT ....
FROM Table s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable t
                 WHERE t.type = s.type and t.category = s.category)
```

And so on..

Comment: That's why I said depends on the requirement.. Every case should be dealt differently  @jarlh , just gave him some info .

Comment: Actually no one would try this method as there are easier ways .. I was just trying to understand how this works. I've just started learning Database :/ 
Trying to solve different cases with simple SQL operations :)